# Is there a one-click button to upgrade liferay version from 7 to 7.1?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-ide

I am currently using liferay CE 7 and planning to upgrade to 7.1
IS there an one-click button to upgrade? or do i have to follow

[This link](https://dev.liferay.com/es/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/7-1/preparing-an-upgrade-to-liferay-7) which consist of many steps and instructions for upgrading but i assume that is for upgrade from 6 to 7.

Comment: "Computer says no"

Comment: This is the closest you get from something like that (if you use those images): https://www.e-systems.tech/docker-images/-/knowledge_base/docker-images/image-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Any Liferay upgrade requires two main parts:

1. Upgrade of environment.
2. Upgrade of code.

The link details the steps to safely upgrade your environment to 7.1.  The steps listed are required for your upgrade to be successful, so you should absolutely follow them.

The second step, not covered in the content of the provided link, are the changes you need to make to your custom modules to be compatible with Liferay 7.1.  The Liferay IDE has an upgrade assistant which can help tackle some of the grunt work required, but ultimately you may find that you have some manual upgrade work to do there.

Comment: anyway to get instructions on using upgrading assistant and the manual works?

Comment: The documentation is there: https://dev.liferay.com/en/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-1/adapting-to-liferay-7s-api-with-the-code-upgrade-tool

Comment: The link that you have provided is just for code upgrade itself right? meaning i still have to do environment upgrade? and also are these all really necessary to upgrade from 7 to 7.1? the link i have provided seem to be catered for 6.

Comment: The link I gave is only for code.  The process for updating environment is still the same, even though it is 7.0 -> 7.1  You should still have the backups, you still need to run the DB upgrade tool, ...  All of the steps listed in the link you attached represent steps a responsible Liferay admin will do when approaching a Liferay environment upgrade.  You can skip some of these steps in lower environments, but doing so in production is at your own peril.